# string index out of range error using lists and text files (using Python)

Tags: python, list, text-files

I have developed a program that puts a user's username, subject, unit, score and grade into a text file. This is the code:

```
tests.extend([subject, unit, str(score), grade])
print tests

with open("test.txt", "a") as testFile:
    for test in tests:
        userName = test[0]
        subject = test[1]
        unit = test[2]
        score = test[3]
        grade = test[4]

        testFile.write(userName + ';' + subject + ';' + unit + ';' + str(score) + ';' + grade + '\n')
```

It prints:

```
['abc', 'history', 'Nazi Germany', '65', 'C']
```

*('abc' being the username)*

And the following error:

```
grade = test[4]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error? Any ideas?

*Already added in previously in quiz: *

```
quizzes = []  
quizzes.append(userName)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the for loop you are iterating through each word inside one test, not through each test in a list of tests.
So, when you call test[0] or test[4], you are not indexing a characteristic of one test, but you are accidentally getting a character from a characteristic from one test. 
You can fix this by putting brackets around your tests array.
For example:

```
Tests = [['abc', 'history', 'Nazi Germany', '65', 'C'],
         ['test2', 'python', 'iteration', '65', 'C']]
for username, subject, unit, score, grade in tests:
     testFile.write(username + ';' + subject + ';' + unit + ';' + str(score) + ';' + grade + '\n')
```

Now you are iterating through each test within tests, not each characteristic within one test

Comment: alright i edited, just reply if you still have questions

Comment: Yep that's it working now. Thanks for the answer and explanation!